# How to accept a PhD offer

Tags: phd, united-states

I was offered the admission one months ago but I didn't accept right away. What would be best language to accept a PhD offer?

Comment: Can you offer more context to the question, such as your country and the field you are in? Most Ph.D. programs in the US have dedicated websites where you can reply to the offers by clicking some buttons, in which case it is really not necessary to write to the program directly.

Comment: It is New Mexico State University. They accept unofficial test scores  before the admission decision.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do that by signing the offer the letter, scan it, attach to an email with a brief "thank you" write up.

Comment: the offer is offical but I haven't submitted all of the documents. And furthermore there are no indications on the offer-letter that I can sign.

Comment: Why do not you email who is in charge? Maybe the Dept.'s secretary can provide more info/help. What do you mean by "you did not submit all of the documents"? What documents?

Comment: Are there indications on the offer-letter somewhat around "we will be sending you the required paperwork soon"?